# Readings about chiral resolutions at the undergraduate level

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, reference-request, chirality, recrystallization

Does anyone know of a resource which clearly explains the scientific theory and experimental methods involved in chiral resolutions?

I have access to the American Chemical Society, Tetrahedron, Royal Society of Chemistry and many other journals and books.

I am an undergraduate student doing laboratory research. I am about to separate enantiomers, which are atropisomers. I am looking for something that I can understand with my limited experience, as I have only taken two semesters of undergraduate organic chemistry. Also, maybe something brief since I will have to do the resolutions in only a few weeks, but that is less important.

Comment: Unfortunately, separation of enantiomers is not a generally solved problem. It depends very heavily on the functional groups in your substrate. If you're only looking to separate a small amount, I'd recommend chiral prep HPLC.

Comment: I would try and find the book Enantiomers,  Racemates and Resolutions by Jacques, Collet and Wilen